# Animation end goes to initial values

Tags: animation, xamarin.ios, opacity

I run an animation on my buttons where I change i.e. Opacity. When the animation is complete all the button's Opacity goes back to initial values. The code:

```
CABasicAnimation animation =  CABasicAnimation.FromKeyPath("opacity");
animation.To = NSNumber.FromFloat( 0.1f );
animation.Duration = animationDuration;
animation.TimingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction.FromName (CAMediaTimingFunction.EaseOut);
```

How can I set the animation to stay in the To value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the error in the code, but there is another way to do that instead of `CoreAnimation`, which is a bit verbose.

For UIKit elements it is usually easier to use the `UIView.Animate` method. So , your sample would be:

```
UIView.Animate (
    animationDuration,
    0,
    UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut,
    delegate {yourButton.Alpha = 0.1f; },
    null);
```

Comment: Dekuji! Now it says '[UIApplication endIgnoringInteractionEvents] called without matching -beginIgnoringInteractionEvents. Ignoring.' on each animation run. It does not crash just writes this into the debug window. Any idea about that?

Comment: The UIApplication class provides a centralized point of control and coordination for applications running on iOS.

endIgnoring... Tells the receiver to resume the handling of touch-related events. Is called when the animation or transition concludes, I guess just ignore that, it is just a verbose info (AFAIK).

Comment: How can I add a scale animation into that to make the buttons 4-times bigger? Setting AffineTransform does not work using your code.

Comment: Well to make things "interesting" in iOS there is a third way to animate UIView stuff.

Code below is taken directly from my code, it combines two tranformation rotation and scale.

UIView.BeginAnimations (null);
UIView.SetAnimationCurve (UIViewAnimationCurve.EaseIn);
UIView.SetAnimationDuration (0.09);
UIView.SetAnimationDelegate (this);
UIView.SetAnimationDidStopSelector (new Selector ("animateShowUp2:"));
   
this.View.Transform = CGAffineTransform.Multiply (rotation, CGAffineTransform.MakeScale (1.2f, 1.2f));
   
UIView.CommitAnimations ();